# postgressql - performance when searching a phone number column using LIKE operator

Tags: postgresql

I have a phone number column in my database that could potentially have somewhere close to 50 million records.

As I have the phone numbers stored with the country code, I am a bit confused on how to implement the search functionality.

Options I have in mind

1. When the user puts in a phone number to search - use the LIKE operator to find the right phone number [When using LIKE operator does it slow down the search?]
2. Split the phone number column into two one with just the area code and the other with the phone number. [Why I am looking into this implmentation is I dont have to use LIKE operator here]

Please suggest any other ideas! People here who has really good experience with postgres please chime in with the best practises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are stored with a country code, you can just include the country code when you search for them.  That should be by far the most performant.  If you know what country each person is in, or if your user base is dominantly from one country, you could just add the  code to "short" numbers in order to complete it.

If LIKE is too slow (at 50 million rows it probably would be) you can put a [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) index on it.  You will probably need to remove, or at least standardize, the punctuation in both data and in the query, or it could cause problems with the LIKE (as well as every other method).

The problem I see with making two columns, country code (plus area code?  I would expect that to go in the other column) and one column for the main body of the number, is that it probably wouldn't do what people want.  I would think people are going to either expect partial matching at any number of digits they feel like typing meaning you would still need to use LIKE, or people who type in the full number (minus country code) are going to expect it to find only numbers in "their" country.  On the other hand splitting off the country code from the main body of the number might avoid having an extremely common country code pollute any pg_trgm indexes you do build with low selectivity trigrams.

Comment: Can't make the user search with the country code? Want to make it easy for the user. I would like to try the pg_trgm option still keeping the like operator. I am sorry it was not one million records, it could potentially reach a lot more than that. Will correct the original post.

Comment: jjanes I haven't tested this as of now with 50 million records, I am just looking for support on the best way to go about this. I would be triggering the search only when the user punches a 10 digit phone number.